# Server angular-ls:xxxxx/starting exited with status exit in Emacs LSP

Tags: angular, typescript, emacs, language-server-protocol

Each time I open a new TypeScript file in an Angular project, it throws an error

> Server angular-ls:xxxxx/starting exited with status exit(check corresponding stderr for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n)

angular-ls:stderr buffer:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/language-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

There isn't anything related to `@angular/language-service` left in package.json, yarn.lock or tsconfig.json but "something" keeps trying to start it.

Just to be clear, I don't want to disable TypeScript language service/LSP completely(it works fine you close this dialog), I just want to remove the artifacts of `@angular/language-service`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to the question posted, but an answer to a related question: how to fix the above error message.
For me installing angular language server helped:

`npm install -g @angular/language-service@next typescript @angular/language-server`

(run in the project directory)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging: No need to disable it completely. You can just adjust the `lsp-clients-angular-language-server-command` instead.

If you have `@angular/language-server` installed locally(per project) the following elisp in your `.dir-locals.el` would solve the issue:

```elisp
((nil
  (eval . (setq lsp-clients-angular-language-server-command
                (let ((curr-proj-root (projectile-project-root)))
                  `("node"
                    ,(concat curr-proj-root "node_modules/@angular/language-server")
                    "--ngProbeLocations"
                    ,(concat curr-proj-root "node_modules")
                    "--tsProbeLocations"
                    ,(concat curr-proj-root "node_modules")
                    "--stdio"))))))
```

Comment: Could you shed more light on this, for instance how do I know if @angular/language-server is installed locally? I just followed some guides to make my emacs work with simple web-development (react) and simply pasted code into my .emacs. I dont know what most of it does (well, in detail). Now I start an angular project and get that.  Its all very confusing.